# Arithmetic Progression (AP)

Tags: sequences-and-series

An arithmetic progression (AP) has 18 terms. If the sum of the last four terms of the AP is 284. calculate the first term and the common difference

Comment: Can you place your efforts into the question, so we can see where you are struggling?

Comment: This seems like insufficient information.

Comment: Indeed. For example: $71, 71, 71, \ldots, 71$.

Comment: The question has no sequence given. It is from a question paper. Other questions under the same question are: calculate the value of the 9th and the 15th terms, calculate the sum of the first five terms

Comment: quite alright I can solve the first equations for the last four which comes to be `4a+6d = 284`. Now how to get another equation to solve it using simultaneous method that's where I fail

Comment: There's not enough information to get a second equation. The 71-sequence from above satisfies your problem, but e.g. $9,13,17,\ldots$ (i.e. $a=9$ and $d=4$) works as well. There is no unique solution.

Comment: You at least need the value of a term in the sequnce to be able to solve the equations to find the common difference and amy other term.

Answer (score 0):

From your Problem we get $$a_1+14d+a_1+15d+a_1+16d+a_1+17d=284$$ an equation in two unknowns.

Comment: So how can I solve for `a` and `d`?

Comment: Are $$a_1,d$$ integer numbers?

Answer (score 0):

$284$ is a rectangle with sides $4$ and $71$. Notice, if you subtract a multiple of $3$ from $71$ to get the size of the first partition, your difference in $AP$ will become a multiple of $2$ accordingly.

$68+70+72+74=65+69+73+77=62+68+74+80 =\ ...\ = 284$

Since your first term of $AP$ is dependent on the common difference, your problem has many solutions.